# What are the classic/benchmark questions for our site

Tags: discussion, questions

This question was asked:

[Can I use human medicine on dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/400/can-i-use-human-medicine-on-dogs)

I think this is a great question, as it is one of those questions that many people will google. I thought we might brain storm; what other questions like this could we ask?

Comment: As long as no one comes along and posts "Sure, I give my pet all kinds of human medications and it's worked out fine so far!" and gets a bunch of upvotes from people who also didn't have a problem **yet**.

Comment: This is why I voted up the [declawing](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/485/when-is-declawing-a-viable-option) question. It has good answers on why it shouldn't be done and we'll hopefully get a ton of traffic from it (because people do want to declaw their cats), some of which will be from people that we'll convince not to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I think behavioral questions are usually very valuable/useful things to refer to (it's definitely the topic I Google the most).

Aside from that, medical questions/advice are again both great to refer to and would gain traffic on the site, as most people would Google them anyway (especially considering a Vet bill being very expensive these days, it's easier and cheaper to seek *semi-professional* help first).

Answer (score 1):

Classic benchmark question are most probably on behavior or health issue like we already have some -

[How to manage hair shedding in dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-to-manage-hair-shedding-in-dogs)

[Why is my dog eating poop?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/470/why-is-my-dog-eating-poop)

So the common behavior problems and health issues appears to me the benchmark questions and we are going to get lots of them sooner or later.